# Backup every replaced file through sed in a `backup` directory of my hd?

Tags: sed, replace

I'm aware you can specify `-i.bak` but I don't want to deal with having to remove `.bak` files, even if it's as simple as:

`find . -name '*.bak' -exec rm {} \;`

Is there some way I can audit `sed` so that by default, anytime I specify `-i` it backs every single file that it inline-replaces, to something like `/www/backups`?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to inline replace without any backup file at all, just leave the extension off: `sed -i 's/pat/rep/'`.

As for backing up elsewhere, [GNU sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Invoking-sed.html) says:

> This rule is followed: if the extension doesn't contain a *, then it
>   is appended to the end of the current filename as a suffix; if the
>   extension does contain one or more * characters, then each asterisk is
>   replaced with the current filename. This allows you to add a prefix to
>   the backup file, instead of (or in addition to) a suffix, or even to
>   place backup copies of the original files into another directory
>   (provided the directory already exists).

It appears an asterisk in the backup "suffix" will be replaced with the file name (including path - so if you have subfolders, you need to create them in the backup directory first).

```
% seq 5 > file
% sed -i'backups/*.bak' s/3/c/ file
% cat file
1
2
c
4
5
% cat backups/file.bak
1
2
3
4
5
%
```

Comment: This solution will fail on ecryptfs filesystems with `sed: cannot rename foo: Invalid cross-device link`.